# Adding Data to an Object - Validate *then* add, or validate as you add?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

Take the following example,

```
class Cup {}

class MyObject {
    protected $cups = array();

    public function addCup(Cup $cup) {
        if (!in_array($cup, $this->getCups())) {
            array_push($this->cups, $cup);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function addCups(array $cups) {
        // Add cups logic, see below
    }

    public function getCups() {
        return $this->cups;
    }

    public function setCups(array $cups) {
        // Set cups logic, see below
    }
}
```

On this class we can add a `Cup` using `$myObject->addCup()`, but we can also add multiple cups using `$myObject->addCups()`, or override any existing cups with `$myObject->setCups()`.

**My question is**, in the `addCups()` and `setCups()` methods, do you validate all the passed data is valid *before* adding them, or do you validate *as* you add them?

**Scenario 1**, validate *before* you add:

```
public function addCups(array $cups) {
    foreach($cups as $cup) {
        if (!($cup instanceof Cup)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException();
        }
    }
    foreach($cups as $cup) {
        $this->addCup($cup);
    }
}
```

**Scenario 2**, validate *as* you add:

```
public function addCups(array $cups) {
    foreach($cups as $cup) {
        if (!($cup instanceof Cup)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException();
        }
        $this->addCup($cup);
    }
}
```

I appreciate there isn't much difference in the code, but it fundamentally changes how the object adds/sets data. In scenario 1, you can only add new data to the object if all the data you are adding is valid, where as in scenario 2 data will actually be added up to the point of the error.

I personally have been using scenario 1, but I can't help but feel you might as well use scenario 2 because if you've thrown an exception, you shouldn't really be carrying on with the execution anyway?

I'd love to know if there's a concrete design pattern to follow on this, or if not people's opinions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all items first.

This allows for transactional behavior, which is generally a Good Thing. This ensures the behavior is easy to understand and debug.

Performance wise, it is also preferable.

However, if your goal is to "do as much work as possible", then check each item and add it if possible - if one item fails, just skip over to the next. This is a rare use case, though.

Comment: Going on Per Holmäng's answer I would agree. I can think of very few use cases where you'd use scenario 2. I'll stick 1 for now as it also fits what I need. Cheers for the sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on wether or not you want to treat adding of 'Cups' as a transaction or not. Do you want adding of all the Cups to fail when one or several Cup(s) fails, use method 1. Otherwise, method 2.

As far as I know, both methods are viable and have their own use-cases.

Comment: That's ultimately the question. In most cases I would see it needing to be transactional. In my particular use case if something goes wrong while adding data, the whole process needs to stop, as it is technically a Logic exception.